# Reading from a File in current User appdata folder for C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, readfile, userappdatapath

I'm trying to read from a file inside the current user's appdata folder in C#, but I'm still learning so I have this:

```
int counter = 0;
string line;

// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("c:\\test.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
    counter++;
}

file.Close();

// Suspend the screen.
Console.ReadLine();
```

But I don't know what to type to make sure it's always the current user's folder.

Comment: Also I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio C# 2010 Express

Answer (score 6):

I might be misunderstanding your question but if you want to to get the current user appdata folder you could use this:

```
string appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

so your code might become:

```
string appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
);
string filePath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, "test.txt");
using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

or even shorter:

```
string appDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(
    Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData
);
string filePath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, "test.txt");
File.ReadAllLines(filePath).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby.aspx) method, and the [Environment.SpecialFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) enumeration. To get the current user's app data folder, you can use either:

- `Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData )` to get application directory for the current, *roaming* user. This directory is stored on the server and it's loaded onto a local system when the user logs on, or
- `Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData )` to get the application directory for the current, *non-roaming* user. This directory is not shared between the computers on the network.

Also, use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) to combine your directory and the file name into a full path:

```
var path = Path.Combine( directory, "test.txt" );
```

Consider using [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) to read the lines from the file. See Remarks on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503.aspx) about the differences between `File.ReadLines` and `File.ReadAllLines`.

```
 foreach( var line in File.ReadLines( path ) )
 {
     Console.WriteLine( line );
 }
```